# Trouble understanding the electrostatic field's curl

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, differential-geometry, potential, conservative-field

I'm going over [Griffiths Electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Electrodynamics), and I've encountered a sort of proof about why we can state an electrostatic field is conservative, using [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). Of course, I do understand if you have a point charge at the origin, its potential will vary according to the path integral:

$$\Delta V = -\int_a^b \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{1}{r_B}-\frac{1}{r_A}\right) \Longrightarrow \oint_P \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=0$$

I also understand Stokes' theorem, and I know we can express the integral above as a surface integral:

$$\int_S (\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E})\cdot d\vec{A}=\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$$

What I can't seem to grasp, is why just because the right hand side of the equation above is $0$, then $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E}=0$ as well.

Could the integral not be $0$, rather than what is inside the integral? To put it the other way around, if we were to compute $\int_S (\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{E})\cdot d\vec{A}$ and obtained $0$, it would make no sense whatsoever to claim that what is being integrated on the other side, $\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$, is $0$ too because what is null is the integral, not what is inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fixed path, your concern is valid; however, the path is arbitrary. So if it holds for all possible paths, the curl is zero.